# How to access and assign object type variable value in terraform root

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

**Objective:** How to access and assign object type variable value from terraform root config

**Code I am trying:**

I am using modules in terraform. The following is one module I am using to create a cosmos DB account

**child module:**

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosaccount" {
  name                = var.account_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name  
  offer_type          = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_offer_type
  kind                = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_kind
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = "true"
  ip_range_filter     = var.cosmos_db_config.ip_range_filter
  enable_automatic_failover = false
  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_consistancy_level
    max_interval_in_seconds = 5
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100
  }
  geo_location {
    location          = var.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
  tags = var.tags
}
```

**child module variable.tf:**

```
variable "cosmos_db_config" {
  default = {
    cosmosdb_offer_type = ""
    cosmosdb_kind   = ""
    cosmosdb_consistancy_level = ""
    ip_range_filter = ""
  }
  type = object(
    {
    cosmosdb_offer_type = string
    cosmosdb_kind   = string
    cosmosdb_consistancy_level = string
    ip_range_filter = string
    }
  )
}
```

**main root variable.tf:**

```
variable "cosmos_db_config" {
  default = {
    cosmosdb_offer_type = ""
    cosmosdb_kind   = ""
    cosmosdb_consistancy_level = ""
    ip_range_filter = ""
  }
  type = object(
    {
    cosmosdb_offer_type = string
    cosmosdb_kind   = string
    cosmosdb_consistancy_level = string
    ip_range_filter = string
    }
  )
}
```

**Module call:**

```
module "cosmosdb" {  
  source = "../modules/cosmosdb"
  account_name = "test"
  rg_name  = module.resource_group.name
  location = module.resource_group.location
  cosmosdb_offer_type = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_offer_type
  cosmosdb_kind = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_kind
  ip_range_filter = var.cosmos_db_config.ip_range_filter
  #subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  cosmosdb_consistancy_level = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_consistancy_level
  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

**terraform.tfvars.json:**

```
"cosmos_db_config": {
        "cosmosdb_offer_type": "Standard",
        "cosmosdb_kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
        "cosmosdb_consistancy_level": "Session",
        "ip_range_filter": ""
    },
```

**Error I get:**

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on cosmosdb.tf line 6, in module "cosmosdb":
│    6:   cosmosdb_offer_type = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_offer_type
│ 
│ An argument named "cosmosdb_offer_type" is not expected here
```

Can you please suggest what mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: You actually only need to pass `var.cosmos_db_config` to the child module and then access the corresponding variable attributes, as you are already doing.

Comment: @MarkoE  thank you... do you mean   `cosmosdb_consistancy_level = var.cosmos_db_config` is enough in module call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to pass the variable that the module is expecting and that is `cosmos_db_config` and not the variable attributes:

```
module "cosmosdb" {  
  source = "../modules/cosmosdb"
  account_name       = "test"
  rg_name            = module.resource_group.name
  location           = module.resource_group.location
  cosmosdb_db_config = var.cosmos_db_config

  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

Comment: Oh this means first we need to do first   `cosmosdb_db_config = var.cosmos_db_config` then `ip_range_filter    = var.cosmos_db_config.ip_range_filter` which is part of above `cosmos_db_config` ?

Comment: Edited the answer, forgot to remove the `ip_range_filter`, that is not needed.

Comment: oh so once you refer whole object in module call then, we dont need to call attributes in  it right ? assuming attributes will be available automatically

Comment: Not in the module call, but the child module code should remain as is.

Comment: one quick question: evn if variable type  = any behaves same way ?

Comment: It probably would behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
cosmosdb_offer_type = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_offer_type
```

You need to pass:

```
cosmosdb_offer_type = var.cosmos_db_config
```

because the variable in the module is an object and not just a string.

---

Another solution, you can create a new variable string in the module, so you can pass `cosmosdb_offer_type = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_offer_type`, example:

child module variable.tf:

```
variable "cosmosdb_offer_type " {
  default = ""
  type    = string
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosaccount" {
  name                = var.account_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name  
  offer_type          = var.cosmosdb_offer_type # <---
```

Then

```
module "cosmosdb" {  
  ....
  cosmosdb_offer_type = var.cosmos_db_config.cosmosdb_offer_type # <---
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, person who reviewed my code dont want to see too many variables in variables.tf wanted me to create a object for related variable ..haha.. earlier i had all independent string variables which was working fine. but code reviewer rejected it

Comment: I suggest two solutions, you can take whatever you want :)